# ContentControl Wrapping Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to create a Custom tooltip Control. This control is inherited from ToolTip class. My Custom Tooltip will have a header and a content area. Content could be normal text or any other content (Image, richtextbox etc). Following is the Template Style that custom tooltip control.

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControls:FlyoutHelp}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0" Margin="15" Width="300">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.7"  />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <StackPanel  TextBlock.FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" TextBlock.FontSize='12'>
                        <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource DellBlue}" Height="23" Foreground="#FFFFFF" Padding="0,4,0,0"  TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding HeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Border Background="{StaticResource DellLightGrey}" TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource DarkestGrey}" Padding="8">
                            <ContentControl   Content="{Binding HelpContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"   />
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Now as you can see in my template that I am using ContentControl for showing the content of the tooltip. The problem is when my HelpContent is just plain String, it doesn't wrap that text. I can't replace ContentControl with TextBlock because HelpContent could be some other type too (image, richtextbox etc). Can anyone please provide me what is the best way to fix this problem? I will be really very thankful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `ContentControl` tag with:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HelpContent}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

[Note: you can leave it as a `ContentControl`, but `ContentPresenter` is lighter and follows conventions]

Comment: What's the advantage of using TemplateBinding here compared to Binding? I thought TemplateBinding is just to inherit default properties of a control.

Comment: From the point of view of what value is assigned, `TemplateBinding` is exactly as using regular binding with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`. It has limitations (like no `Mode=TwoWay` or StringFormat) but the big plus is that it's validated at compile-time - so, if you make a mistake in spelling of the property you'd get build error when using `TemplateBinding`. With regular binding build will succeed but then you'd spend long minutes/hours figuring out why the template/control looks wrong. R# helps even with regular binding, but `TemplateBinding` is safer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `StackPanel` to `Grid` since it doesn't know the width for it to wrap.

```
<Grid TextBlock.FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" TextBlock.FontSize='12'>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinitions/>
     <RowDefinitions/>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource DellBlue}" Height="23" Foreground="#FFFFFF" Padding="0,4,0,0"  TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding HeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
  <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource DellLightGrey}" TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource DarkestGrey}" Padding="8">
    <ContentControl   Content="{Binding HelpContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"   />
  </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: By default, `StackPanel` has `Orientation=Horizontal`. In that case, `StackPanel` is "blocking" its children on the X-Axis but not on the Y-Axis. So the `TextBlock` will "feel" the boundary and will wrap.